# How to get track metadata from acoustID with Python

Tags: python-3.x, musicbrainz

I have a file.mp3 with unknown tags. I've used this to get the acoustID:

```
import acoustid
acoustID= acoustid.match(API_KEY, filepath)
```

`acoustID` contains several candidates, let's say I choose the best one: '0f6eb38a-d6c9-4f87-a9a7-6e7b0eeb4281'.

I've tried this but it doesn't give many info:

```
import musicbrainzngs
musicbrainzngs.get_recording_by_id(acoustID)
```

How to get the corresponding **tags (album, tack number, genre, band, etc...) from this acoustID ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found this: https://acousticbrainz.org/. From your browser you can use this url: `https://acousticbrainz.org/<my acoustID>`. From your code you can get a big json data file with all metadata on this track from this url: `https://acousticbrainz.org/api/v1/<my acoustID>/low-level`

For a python script you can use something like this:

```
import acoustid
import urllib.request, json

file = "path/to/myAudioFile"
API_KEY = 'cSpUJKpD'

candidates = acoustid.match(API_KEY, file)  # returns a generator of candidates

best_score, best_acoustId, best_title, best_artist = next(candidates)

metadata = {}
with urllib.request.urlopen("https://acousticbrainz.org/api/v1/" + best_acoustId + "/low-level") as url:
    data = json.loads(url.read().decode())
    metadata = data['metadata']
```

For more info about `acoustid.match()` you can check their github page, especially here: https://github.com/beetbox/pyacoustid/blob/master/aidmatch.py

Answer (score 1):

Your `acoustID` is not an acoustid, but the [MusicBrainz Identifier (MBID)](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_Identifier) of a [Recording](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/Recording).

You're correct that `musicbrainzngs.get_recording_by_id` by default only returns a very small set of data. It's a wrapper around the [MusicBrainz lookup](https://musicbrainz.org/doc/MusicBrainz_API#Lookups) API that returns data based on what was requested via the `inc` parameter. That is available in musicbrainzngs as the `includes` parameter to the `get_*_by_id` functions. If you use

```py
musicbrainzngs.get_recording_by_id("0f6eb38a-d6c9-4f87-a9a7-6e7b0eeb4281", includes=["artists", "releases"])
```

more data - in this case about the artists of the recording and the releases it appears on - will be returned. You need to define yourself (or ask the user) to chose the correct release, because you can't tell from the MBID of the recording alone which release the should be considered "correct".